# SQL: Copy value from column to another row in same column if condition is met

Tags: sql, oracle

This should be a relatively easy question to answer, but because it's been a little while since I took DB in undergrad and don't have my notes (I probably should, yeah?) I need to ask the internet for help.

I have a DB table of questions and answers. Each question has an ID, each answer has a value, and each of these is related to a certain user.

Here's a simplified example of how it looks.

[image: Input]

What I want to do is change the answers to all question B's replacing them with that users answer to question A. Like so:

[image: Output]

If there are other questions and answers for the user, I don't want to touch those. I just want to replace the value for question B.
So. Um... how do I do that?

Comment: so do you want all the question_id's for a user_id replaced with answer from question_id A for that user?

Comment: See the images. I want ANSWER_VALUE for question B to be set to ANSWER_VALUE of question A, but for each user individually. The highlighted values in red on the second image are what I want to have change.

Comment: I also just re-read your comment and realize that I misinterpreted it. I think you're correct. (This is also why I'm asking humans instead of a computer and why I'm using pictures. It's hard for me to put into words exactly what I want)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this using PL/SQL. This code is edited to remove any hints of what I'm working on, as this was for work, but this is the general gist of what I did.

```
DECLARE
q_id_from_update varchar2(45);
q_id_to_update varchar2(45);
BEGIN
    SELECT QUESTION_ID
    INTO q_id_to_update
    FROM QUESTION
    WHERE QUESTION.NAME = 'QUESTION_A';

    SELECT QUESTION_ID
    INTO q_id_from_update
    FROM QUESTION
    WHERE QUESTION.NAME = 'QUESTION_B';

FOR a IN (SELECT
        ANSWER.QUESTION_ID,
        ANSWER.USER_ID,
        ANSWER.ANSWER
    FROM ANSWER
    WHERE ANSWER.QUESTION_ID = q_id_from_update AND
        ANSWER.ANSWER IS NOT NULL)
    LOOP
        UPDATE ANSWER
        SET ANSWER.ANSWER = a.ANSWER
        WHERE ANSWER.USER_ID = a.USER_ID AND
            ANSWER.QUESTION_ID = q_id_to_update;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

select t1 SET ANSWER_VALUE = (SELECT QUESTION_ID, USER_ID FORM t2 where t1.Question_Id= t2.Question_Id && t1.User_Id = t2.User_Id);

Comment: Is that a joke? Or perhaps that is syntax from another product, not Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the answer id's are A, B, C, etc., and that they are all present for every user_id, this can be solved using the analytic function `lag()`, conditionally on the `question_id`. Note that, in general, `answer_value` may be null, and if the `A` answer was null but the `B` answer actually had a value, the `B` answer will be erased (replaced with null). I added to the test data to illustrate. This also assumes that every user has only one row for each question (the combination `question_id, user_id` is unique in the table).

```
with
     db_table ( question_id, user_id, answer_value ) as (
       select 'A', 'JIM' , 1    from dual union all
       select 'B', 'JIM',  2    from dual union all
       select 'C', 'JIM',  4    from dual union all
       select 'A', 'PAUL', 3    from dual union all
       select 'B', 'PAUL', 1    from dual union all
       select 'C', 'PAUL', 3    from dual union all
       select 'A', 'MIKE', 2    from dual union all
       select 'B', 'MIKE', 1    from dual union all
       select 'C', 'MIKE', 4    from dual union all
       select 'A', 'ANN' , null from dual union all
       select 'B', 'ANN' , 2    from dual union all
       select 'C', 'ANN' , 4    from dual
     )
-- end of test data; SQL query begins below this line
select question_id, user_id,
       case when question_id = 'B'
            then lag(answer_value) over (partition by user_id order by question_id)
            else answer_value end as answer_value
from   db_table
;
```

**Output**:

```
QUESTION_ID USER_ID ANSWER_VALUE
----------- ------- ------------
A           ANN
B           ANN
C           ANN                4
A           JIM                1
B           JIM                1
C           JIM                4
A           MIKE               2
B           MIKE               2
C           MIKE               4
A           PAUL               3
B           PAUL               3
C           PAUL               3

12 rows selected.
```