# Copy value to another row based on similar ID

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I am looking for a way to achieve the following in SQL:

Say I have a table:

| UniqeID | AccountNo | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | 001ID | stack500 |
| efg567 | 001ID | null |

What I am trying to achieve is if `AccountNo` are same, I would like to fill that null with the value above it. Basically, for my purposes, if `AccountNo`. then value must be same. I tried the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511063/sql-copy-value-from-column-to-another-row-in-same-column-if-condition-is-met)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```sql
UPDATE ttable --(or t1)
SET t1.Value = t2.Value 
FROM 
    ttable as t1
JOIN ttable as t2 ON t1.AccountNo = t2.AccountNo
WHERE t1.value IS NULL
AND t2.value IS NOT NULL
```